# Java - Recursive double factorial algorithm

Tags: java, recursion

could anybody help me to improve this algorithm? It's a recursive function which is basically doing fact(n) * fact(n) but I can't figure out how to make it more efficient.

```
static long doubleFactorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    System.out.println("DoubleFactorial(" + n + ") called");
    return n * doubleFactorial(n - 1) & doubleFactorial(n - 1);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: calling twice doubleFactorial(n-1) isn't good. Store the result in a variable and multiply it

Comment: You could also drop the recursion and use a for loop.

Comment: @D.Lawrence Thanks for the quick reply! Something like this? long result = doubleFactorial( n - 1 ); return n * n * result; That doesn't return the same result for anything above 4 though, I'm a bit confused as to why.

Comment: In your question your code uses `&` instead of `*`. That's why it's different.

Comment: @D.Lawrence I'm stupid, I can just return the result^2 of course.

Comment: Recursion is interesting and fun but if you're looking for efficiency, don't use recursion for this.

Comment: `&` is bitwise AND, squaring could be done: `long df = doubleFactorial(n - 1); return n * df * df;`

Comment: Do you mean **Double Factorial** as in for example **5!!** described here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-factorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic [image], doesn't return `fact(n) * fact(n)` 
if you want so, You can define [image] for example :

```
f(0)=1
f(1)=1
f(2)=2^2*f(1)=4*f(1)
.
.    
f(10)=10^2*f(9)
.
.
f(n)=n^2*f(n-1)
```

So you can use the below code:

```
static long doubleFactorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    System.out.println("DoubleFactorial(" + n + ") called");
    return n * n * doubleFactorial(n - 1);
}
```

Try online [doubleFactorial(5)=14400](https://onlinegdb.com/SJLC_e8WL)

Answer (score 0):

Just save it to a variable and don't call it 2 times:

Here is your code(assuming you want to multiply the factorials and not AND them)

```
static long doubleFactorial(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return 1; 
    System.out.println("DoubleFactorial(" + n + ") called");
    long fact=doubleFactorial(n - 1);
    return n * fact * fact;
}
```

Also, it would be more efficient if you remove the recursion(but you may not want that):

```
static long doubleFactorial(int n){
    long ret=1;
    for(int i=2;i<n;i++){
        ret=i*ret*ret;
    }
}
```

This replaces the recursion with a loop what reduces the number of method calls and therefore improves the performance.

Also, it will not create a massive stack(and possibly `StackOverflowError`s)